# Android camera apps: Need to fully init preview surface before setting previewCallback?

Tags: android, android-camera

I have a question about the Camera previewCallback in Android.  My app has 2 main parts, the Activity that opens the camera and configures its parameters, and then a subclass of SurfaceView that's used to display the preview.  I'm testing on 4.0.4

If the Activity implements Camera.PreviewCallback and I do something like this:

```
Public Class PreviewFrameActivity extends Activity implements Camera.PreviewCallback {<br />
     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       // setup layout and create SurfaceView object before getting here
       Camera mCamera = Camera.open();
       mCamera.setPreviewCallback(this);
     } 

     public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
       Log.d(TAG, "Starting frame processing...");
     }
 }
```

The previewCallback never actually gets called doing it this way.  However, if I have my SurfaceView implement PreviewCallback and set it on the camera object as part of surfaceCreated, then all the sudden the callback starts working.  This leads me to believe that even though the docs say that setPreviewCallback can be called at anytime, that's not actually the case.  Much like startPreview(), it seems like you can't call setPreviewFormat until after you have a valid preview Surface (which is why it started worked when I moved the code into the block that starts the preview after the Surface was created).  Can someone confirm this for me?

Comment: The must have updated the docs: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html